# JSON incrementar vários itens do pedido em php

Tags: php, json, api

Colegas, essa função faz a inclusão de um pedido com um item de venda. Eu gostaria de fazer que ela inserisse não apenas um item, mas vários de acordo com a quantidade que eu tenha no meu banco de dados. Sei que tenho que fazer select na base antes, mas o que não estou sabendo fazer é um foreach para incluir quantos itens de venda eu tenha pra o meu pedido.

O trecho de código que preciso para deixar dinâmico e incremental é este:

```
"produto" => [
          "cfop" => "5.102",//dinamico
          "codigo_produto" => "1398561571",//dinamico
          "descricao" => "Mouse sem fio Microsoft",//dinamico
          "ncm" => "9504.10.99",
          "quantidade" => 1,//varia
          "tipo_desconto" => "V",//varia
          "unidade" => "UN",
          "valor_desconto" => 0,
          "valor_unitario" => 200
        ]
```

Aqui está o código completo:

```
 function getPedido() {
    $cod_pedido_integracao = 9;
  $pedido = [
    "cabecalho" => [
      "codigo_cliente" => 1398561351,//dinamico
      "codigo_pedido_integracao" => "$cod_pedido_integracao",//dinamico
      "data_previsao" => "21/12/2020",//dinamico
      "etapa" => "10",//fixo
      "numero_pedido" => "4",//dinamico
      "codigo_parcela" => "999",//fixo
      "quantidade_itens" => 2//dinamico
    ],
    "det" => [
      [
        "ide" => [
          "codigo_item_integracao" => "999"//fixo
        ],
        "inf_adic" => [
          "peso_bruto" => 150,//dinamico
          "peso_liquido" => 150//dinamico
        ],
        "produto" => [
          "cfop" => "5.102",//dinamico
          "codigo_produto" => "1398561571",//dinamico
          "descricao" => "Mouse sem fio Microsoft",//dinamico
          "ncm" => "9504.10.99",
          "quantidade" => 1,//varia
          "tipo_desconto" => "V",//varia
          "unidade" => "UN",
          "valor_desconto" => 0,
          "valor_unitario" => 200
        ]
      ]
    ],
    "frete" => [
      "modalidade" => "9"
    ],
    "informacoes_adicionais" => [
      "codigo_categoria" => "1.01.03",
      "codigo_conta_corrente" => 1398561339,
      "consumidor_final" => "S",
      "enviar_email" => "N"
    ],
    "lista_parcelas" => [
      "parcela" => [
        [
          "data_vencimento" => "22/12/2020",
          "numero_parcela" => 1,
          "percentual" => 50,
          "valor" => 100
        ],
        [
          "data_vencimento" => "08/02/2021",
          "numero_parcela" => 2,
          "percentual" => 50,
          "valor" => 100
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ];

  return $pedido;
}
```

Comment: Vc pretende que esse seu objeto `$pedido` tenha um lista em `produto`? E essa lista de produtos fosse criada com um foreach para adicionar produtos? Seria isso??

Comment: Isso mesmo que quero fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez a sua dificuldade esteja no fato que o seu input é feito com arrays. Transformando-o em objeto ficaria mais simples a manipulação. De todo modo segue código alterado para incluir um `foreach` de uma lista de produtos e adicioná-los à `$pedido`. Essa mesma lógica poderia ser feita sem o `foreach`, atribuindo diretamente o valor à `$pedido["det"][0]["produtos"]`.

Fiddle: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d1d03cacc3fc672b2385ed00e6fdfcc65fa1722b

Código:

```php
<?php
function getPedido() {
  $cod_pedido_integracao = 9;
  $pedido = [
    "cabecalho" => [
      "codigo_cliente" => 1398561351,//dinamico
      "codigo_pedido_integracao" => "$cod_pedido_integracao",//dinamico
      "data_previsao" => "21/12/2020",//dinamico
      "etapa" => "10",//fixo
      "numero_pedido" => "4",//dinamico
      "codigo_parcela" => "999",//fixo
      "quantidade_itens" => 2//dinamico
    ],
    "det" => [
      [
        "ide" => [
          "codigo_item_integracao" => "999"//fixo
        ],
        "inf_adic" => [
          "peso_bruto" => 150,//dinamico
          "peso_liquido" => 150//dinamico
        ],
        "produtos" => array()
      ]
    ],
    "frete" => [
      "modalidade" => "9"
    ],
    "informacoes_adicionais" => [
      "codigo_categoria" => "1.01.03",
      "codigo_conta_corrente" => 1398561339,
      "consumidor_final" => "S",
      "enviar_email" => "N"
    ],
    "lista_parcelas" => [
      "parcela" => [
        [
          "data_vencimento" => "22/12/2020",
          "numero_parcela" => 1,
          "percentual" => 50,
          "valor" => 100
        ],
        [
          "data_vencimento" => "08/02/2021",
          "numero_parcela" => 2,
          "percentual" => 50,
          "valor" => 100
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ];

  $produtos = array(
    [
      "cfop" => "1",//dinamico
      "codigo_produto" => "1398561571",//dinamico
      "descricao" => "Mouse sem fio Microsoft",//dinamico
      "ncm" => "9504.10.99",
      "quantidade" => 1,//varia
      "tipo_desconto" => "V",//varia
      "unidade" => "UN",
      "valor_desconto" => 0,
      "valor_unitario" => 200
    ],
    [
      "cfop" => "2",//dinamico
      "codigo_produto" => "1398561571",//dinamico
      "descricao" => "Mouse sem fio Microsoft",//dinamico
      "ncm" => "9504.10.99",
      "quantidade" => 1,//varia
      "tipo_desconto" => "V",//varia
      "unidade" => "UN",
      "valor_desconto" => 0,
      "valor_unitario" => 200
    ],
    [
      "cfop" => "3",//dinamico
      "codigo_produto" => "1398561571",//dinamico
      "descricao" => "Mouse sem fio Microsoft",//dinamico
      "ncm" => "9504.10.99",
      "quantidade" => 1,//varia
      "tipo_desconto" => "V",//varia
      "unidade" => "UN",
      "valor_desconto" => 0,
      "valor_unitario" => 200
    ]);

  foreach ($produtos as $produto) {
      array_push($pedido["det"][0]["produtos"], $produto);
  }

  return $pedido;
}

$pedido = getPedido();
var_dump($pedido["det"][0]["produtos"]);
```